# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream: docker + nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**I really need some help!**

Hello, I am trying to get a Kirby-Service up and running but my setup keeps crashing. I have spent a week now trying everything, making research etc.

I have a working nginx reverse proxy by jwilder. But because I need a completeley new and custom .conf file I have added another nginx service which should than serve my php application.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:

  nfs_subdomain:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my-image
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kirby
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    expose:
      - 9001
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html


  nfs_nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    links:
      - nfs_subdomain
    volumes_from:
      - nfs_subdomain
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=sub.domain.tld
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=sub.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com
    networks:
      - kirby
      - proxy-tier

networks:
  kirby:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginxproxy_default
```

`nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  upstream kirby_server {
    server nfs_subdomain:9001;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    listen 9001;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_pass kirby_server;
    }
  }
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install packages: web server & PHP plus extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  git \
  curl \
  libpng-dev \
  libonig-dev \
  zip \
  unzip

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#probably only laravel stuff
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif bcmath gd

#install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json composer.lock /var/www/html/
RUN composer install

WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER $user
```

The logfile from the `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
nfs_subdomain_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.192.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
nfs_subdomain_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.192.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
nfs_subdomain_1  | [Thu Aug 26 10:55:54.759065 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.22 configured -- resuming normal operations
nfs_subdomain_1  | [Thu Aug 26 10:55:54.759092 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

And finally the error from the reverse nginx proxy:

```
nginx.1    | 2021/08/26 10:56:18 [error] 1563#1563: *419017 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.xxx.xxx.130, server: sub.domain.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://xxx.xx.0.13:80/", host: "sub.domain.tld"
```

If I do a netstat:

```
netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

```
netstat -npl 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/apache2           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39009        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp     3840      0 127.0.0.11:48035        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Any help is appreciated, I have spent many many hours with this with no success.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a Dockerfile for the FPM, but why isn't it part of docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz it is: 
```build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```
Or what do you mean? I am building the dockerfile successfuly and I take the new created image to start the service.

Comment: oh, now that you say it I see it .. :(